# Positioning UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uidatepicker

Part of my UIDatePicker is extending off the bottom of the screen even though I think I am positioning it correctly. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've gone through the following lines multiple tines and can't figure out where I went wrong. I'm trying to avoid explicitly specifying coordinates for my UIDatePicker's frame. I've included the relevant code from my view controller here:

```
// Create the time picker
self.timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[self.timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

// Set the time picker frame
CGRect screenRect = [self.view frame];
CGSize pickerSize = [self.timePicker sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(screenRect.origin.x,
                               screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                               pickerSize.width,
                               pickerSize.height);
NSLog(@"Picker frame: %f", screenRect.size.height);
NSLog(@"Picker frame: %f", screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height);
[self.timePicker setFrame:pickerRect];

// Add the picker to the view
[self.view addSubview:self.timePicker];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues.

Since you want the picker view to be placed relative to `self.view` you want `screenRect` to be based on `self.view.bounds`, not `self.view.frame`.

Also, never call `sizeThatFits:`. Call `sizeToFit` instead. This is stated in the docs for one of those two methods. But this isn't necessary. The picker view will automatically be the proper size.

Most likely you want the picker view to fill the width of the view (at least on an iPhone/iPod touch). So your `pickerRect` should be:

```
CGSize pickerSize = self.timePicker.bounds.size;
CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0,
                               screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                               screenRect.size.width,
                               pickerSize.height);
```

The last step is to set the `autoresizing` mask for the picker. Since you want the picker pinned to the bottom of the view you should set it up with a flexible top margin. And since you want it the width of the view set it to flexible width:

```
self.timePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: Does it make a difference whether I use `screenRect.size.width` or `pickerSize.width`?

Comment: Sure it does. If you want the picker to fill the view's width then you must use `screenRect.size.width`. Only use `pickerSize.width` if you want the picker to have some other fixed width that is different from the view's width.

Comment: But when I call `sizeToFit`, shouldn't the width of the UITimePicker be the same as width of the current view bounds? I realize the main mistake is that I used the view frame instead of the bounds, but I just want to be sure that I'm doing everything else correctly too.

Comment: Read the docs for `sizeToFit`. Sizing a view in no way takes into account the size of the view's parent view. It sizes itself based on its own subviews. In fact, at the time you call `sizeToFit`, the picker hasn't even been added to its parent view yet. So how could such a call take that size into account? (Hint, it can't).